# Raspbian Jessie+ breaks SPI (RFID Reader MFCR 522)?

Tags: raspbian, spi, rfid

Long version:

I have a very odd problem: I connected a Mifare MFRC 522 RFID Reader to my raspberry Pi (it handles communication via SPI). For that I used one of the many Tutorial already on the Internet. At first everything worked fine but after a few days the Reader didn't detect the rfid chips anymore. 
I was stuck on this for a few weeks, but now i found out, that after a downgrade to Raspbian wheezy, everything works fine and the upgrade to jessie/testing breaks the readers ability to detect rfid chips.

I have seen Threads claiming that enableing SPI + device Tree in raspi-config would solve SPI problems, but it did nothing for me.
Unfortunately i need the newest raspbian version, so staying on wheezy is not an option.

Does anybody have a Idea how i can fix or how i can get to the bottom of this problem?

TLDR:

RFID Reader works in Raspbian wheezy, upgrading to jessie+ makes it not detecting cards. Enableing SPI+Device Tree in raspi-config did not help.

Comment: maybe you had installed some driver that you forgot to reinstall on when changing to Jessie. Also be sure to have make a clean install when moving from wheezy to jessy just in case. I dont know much more

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I did a clean raspbian jessie install on another SD card, and the reader was still broken.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Tests show that SPI is working. I have `dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708` and `dtparam=spi=on` on my /boot/config.txt. I assume you also did that?

Comment: I've got it working in Raspbian Jessie on a Pi 3: `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19v7-aufs #1 SMP Sun Mar 13 12:48:13 CET 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40829/rpi-2-spi-bcm2708-or-spi-bcm2709/47394#47394 for more.

Comment: I assume that you check /dev for SPI ports and there no port.

Did you check any configuration in uEnv.txt?

cd /boot
sudo nano /uEnv.txt

Comment: I assume that you check `/dev` for SPI ports and there is no port. Did you check any configuration in `uEnv.txt`? `cd /boot` then `sudo nano /uEnv.txt`.

Comment: There is no such file

Comment: What is the result of `ls /dev/spidev*/`?